# Control Google Home with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-home, google-smart-home, nest-device-access

I have a Google Nest and a Raspberry Pi. I would like to be able to send commands from the Raspberry to the Google Nest. I have done some research and I have found ways to control the rpi with the Google Nest but not the other way around. Any clue would be helpful Thanks!

EDIT: I think Google Nest may not be the target but the google home app. In the end I want to be able to do something like this: rpi sends request => light device registered in my google home app opens/closes.

Comment: If you think it is not possible please tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the Google Nest using the [Smart Device Management API](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/display).

However, there are currently only a few traits supported for controlling the Nest, specifically targeting the on-board camera.